# Which property to transition on for a sliding effect in a flex-column

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-animations

I have a list that resides in a container that will periodically have items removed/added from the bottom of the container. The container itself is fixed to the lower left of the viewport.

When a new child is appended I would like for all the existing children to slide up and when a child is removed, all the siblings above it to slide down.

I can't figure out which property to `transition` on for the list elements. When I apply `transition: all ...;` to `.toast` it properly animates sliding up when a child is appended -- but not for when a child is removed.

**Clearly because `transition: all` works, the property can be animated, but I can't figure out which property it is.** I've tried `transition: bottom`, `height`, `margin-bottom`, and a couple others -- but they don't achieve what I'm looking for. I'm looking to *avoid* using `transition: all` and would like to apply `transition` to only the property necessary.

**EDIT** To be clear: I am not asking about animating the individual toast entry/exit animation (i.e. the one that is being added/removed) but rather how to control the movement of the *other* toasts that are already present and reflow in order to make room for the addition/fill in for the removal.

Here is a rough sketch of the code.

```js
let counter = 3;
let toasterEl = document.getElementById("toaster");

const newToast = () => toasterEl.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',`<div class="toast">${++counter}</div>`);

const removeToast = () => toasterEl.removeChild(toasterEl.childNodes[toasterEl.childNodes.length - 1])
```

```css
#toaster {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    flex-direction: column;
    max-width: 100px;
    min-height: 100px;
}
.toast {
    transform-origin: center bottom;
    transition: ??? .5s linear;
    animation: toast-entry .5s ease-in;
  
    background-color: tan;
    color: black;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

@keyframes toast-entry {
    0% {
        transform: rotateX(90deg);
        opacity: 0.5;
    }
    50% {
        transform: rotateX(0deg);
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="newToast()">Make toast</button>
<button onclick="removeToast()">Burn toast</button>

<div id="toaster">
    <div class="toast">1</div>
    <div class="toast">2</div>
    <div class="toast">3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You mean like this - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/MMGozZ

Comment: @Paulie_D hmm, something like that. I've updated the question with a codepen example of the functionality I'm trying to achieve https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xojLrE

Comment: CSS frameworks such as materialize [perform this animation in JS](https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/blob/v1-dev/js/toasts.js).

Comment: You also unfortunately can't `transition` a `height` attribute that's set to auto: https://css-tricks.com/using-css-transitions-auto-dimensions/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no easy way to do this using CSS alone, because [`auto`-dimensions cannot be animated](https://css-tricks.com/using-css-transitions-auto-dimensions/). This means you need to know your dimensions a-priori, or you can calculate it on the fly like [libraries such as materialize do](https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/blob/v1-dev/js/toasts.js).

Perhaps something like this:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ydjPMj

```html
<button onclick="newToast()">Make toast</button>
<button onclick="removeToast()">Burn toast</button>

<div id="toaster">
    <div class="toast">1</div>
    <div class="toast">2</div>
    <div class="toast">3</div>
</div>
```

```css
#toaster {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
   height: 100px;
    max-width: 100px;

   transition: height 2s;
}
.toast {
    background-color: tan;
    color: black;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
    width: 100%;
   height: 1em;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```js
let counter = 3;
let toasterEl = document.getElementById("toaster");
toasterEl.style.height = "9em";

const newToast = () => {
   toasterEl.insertAdjacentHTML(
      "beforeend",
      `<div class="toast">${++counter}</div>`
   );
   toasterEl.style.height = parseInt(toasterEl.style.height) + 3 + "em";
};

const removeToast = () => {
  toasterEl.removeChild(toasterEl.childNodes[toasterEl.childNodes.length - 1]);
   toasterEl.style.height = parseInt(toasterEl.style.height) - 3 + "em";
}
```

**[EDIT]** You might also want to [look into `flex-grow`](https://css-tricks.com/using-css-transitions-auto-dimensions/#article-header-id-6), which isn't quite what you want but may help you hack your way to a solution if you know something about the geometry of the DOM inside each toast.

Answer (score 1):

I would rather say the best way to reach the desired effect, is to listen for `transitionend` event on those elements and `.remove()` that element after the transition is finished.

Here is a working example:

```js
let counter = 3;
let toasterEl = document.getElementById("toaster");

const newToast = () => toasterEl.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',`<div class="toast">${++counter}</div>`);

const removeToast = () => { 

  var child = toasterEl.childNodes[ toasterEl.childNodes.length - 1 ];
  
  child.style.height = child.offsetHeight + 'px';
  
  child.addEventListener( 'transitionend', function( e ) {
  
    this.remove();
  
  });
  
  // this is a trick to let browser paint set `offsetHeight` first then start transition from that value to zero
  setTimeout( function() { 
  
    child.style.height = child.style.paddingTop = child.style.paddingBottom = child.style.marginTop = child.style.marginBottom = 0;
    
   }, 10 );

}
```

```css
#toaster {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    flex-direction: column;
    max-width: 200px;
    min-height: 200px;
}
.toast {
    transform-origin: center top;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: height .3s ease-out, margin .3s ease-out, padding .3s ease-out;
    animation: toast-entry .5s ease-in;
    background-color: tan;
    color: black;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align: center;
}

@keyframes toast-entry {
    0% {
        transform: rotateX(90deg);
        opacity: 0.5;
    }
    50% {
        transform: rotateX(0deg);
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="newToast()">Make toast</button>
<button onclick="removeToast()">Burn toast</button>

<div id="toaster">
    <div class="toast">1</div>
    <div class="toast">2</div>
    <div class="toast">3</div>
</div>
```

Worthy mentions:

1. You need to use `transition` on two other `padding` and `margin` properties as well as `height` itself.
2. For the sake of simplicity, I've changed `box-sizing` to `border-box`.
3. If you decided to use this approach, it's better to use other prefixed-event names of `transitionend` too.
4. There's a `e.propertyName` property inside of your event function to use if you want to choose when to remove your element.

[Further information about `transitionend`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_transitionend.asp) and [`.propertyName`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_transition_propertyName.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You're removing the element from the DOM immediatley, so no transition or animation is going to be applied. You can add a class (with animation ) when you want to remove the element and after a set amount of time when transition has finished, remove the element.

```js
let counter = 3;
let toasterEl = document.getElementById("toaster");

const newToast = () => toasterEl.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',`<div class="toast">${++counter}</div>`);

const removeToast = () => {
    toasterEl.childNodes[toasterEl.childNodes.length - 1].classList.add("remove")
    setTimeout(()=>{
        toasterEl.removeChild(toasterEl.childNodes[toasterEl.childNodes.length - 1])    
    },200) 
}
```

```css
#toaster {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    flex-direction: column;
    max-width: 100px;
    min-height: 100px;
}
.toast {
    transform-origin: center bottom;
    transition: all .5s linear;
    animation: toast-entry .5s ease-in;
  
    background-color: tan;
    color: black;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

.remove{
   transform:scaleY(0);
   opacity: 0;
 }


@keyframes toast-entry {
    0% {
        transform: rotateX(90deg);
        opacity: 0.5;
    }
    50% {
        transform: rotateX(0deg);
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="newToast()">Make toast</button>
<button onclick="removeToast()">Burn toast</button>

<div id="toaster">
    <div class="toast">1</div>
    <div class="toast">2</div>
    <div class="toast">3</div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: Hmm, this isn't quite what I meant. I understand the issue about removing/adding an element happening immediately. I've edited my original question to be clearer but I'm looking for how to control the movement of the *other* toasts that are *already* present and reflow in order to make room for the new toast.